# what is the number of bits assigned by a generative model to a K-class dataset, in theory

Tags: maximum-likelihood, information-theory, density-estimation, generative-models

Consider a dataset, something like MNIST or CIFAR-10, that consists of (for example) 50000 images taken from 10 classes and balanced with an equal number in each class.

For a *discriminitive* classifier, I believe that the *expectation* of the negative log likelihood $-\log_2 p_{\theta}(y_k|x_k)$
*before training* (with expectation taken across random model weights) be  $$ \log_2 1/10 = -\log_2 10$$  (please me if this is wrong),
and if the model is perfect the NLL after training will go to zero.

Now the question: *what about fitting a generative/density model to this dataset*.
Let's over-train the model so that it fits the given data as well as possible,
without attempting to generalize beyond the given data, so it will try to assign "spikes" to the data.

What should the NLL be in this case? Of course it depends on the random initial weights and optimization trajectory, but I am interested in a qualitative answer, a typical outcome across different weights. Will it assign equal likelihood to each of the 10 classes (as in the case of a classifier),
or will it assign equal likelihood to each of the 50000 datapoints (I think yes), or some other answer?

The question is from curiousity, not from a book or homework.

Comment: From reading this, I don't see your point about generative models.  // What does it mean to 'assign bits to a dataset'? // You haven't specified the form of your model. In general, with random parameters you have no guarantee that the class probabilities are equal. They could be anything—maybe it always assigns all probability mass to one class.

Comment: Yes you are right. I should have said the "expected" assignment of bits, with expectation taken across weights. By assign bits, I mean bits = -log2(p). Deep learning papers often report bits or bits per dimension on a trained generative model.

Comment: My guess is that it should tend to assign equal likelihood to the 50000 datapoints, and the fact that they are grouped in classes would cause some clustering, but not change the expected coding (or "likelihood"). But I am not sure and want to hear other peole's thoughts.